# What is the purpose of sap.app.title and sap.app.description in manifest.json for standalone app?

Tags: sapui5

When I have a standalone UI5 application started by an index.html what is the purpose of the sap.app.title and sap.app.description property in the manifest.json file?

Can I just leave it out?

```
{
  "_version": "1.1.0",
  "sap.app": {
    "_version": "1.1.0",
    "id": "my.app",
    "type": "application",                    
    "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
    "title": "{{appTitle}}",                  <------- What is it used for?
    "description": "{{appDescription}}",      <------- What is it used for?
    "applicationVersion": {
    "version": "1.0.0"
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot leave the title property out: it states [here](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon20/helpdata/en/be/0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da/content.htm) that the title property is mandatory. The description is optional.

However, I do not think that a stand-alone app uses it, but rather that it is used to distinguish between several apps in the same app group or launchpad (not 100% sure as I also work with a standalone app).